# How to use python library(user defined) function in java program?

Tags: python, java

I am facing some issue with python to java.
I have my python library (test_lib) which have functions (addition, multiply) now I want to use test_lib function in java program but without using (test_lib) in java program. I don't want to show or include function definition in java program. I know if I add python file that have a function I can call in java program but then the user knows the function definition.

Has anyone ever tried python to java. Like with a high level approach?
Thank you.

Comment: *"I want to use test_lib function in java program but without using (test_lib) in java program"* What?

Comment: A few code samples may help to understand the background of the question.

Comment: test_lib is python library which have different types of functions, In java program I want to use my test_lib functions.

Comment: Make things simple. Why are you using such a complicated approach?

Comment: Can you tell any approach ? But I don't want to show my python code or say function definition in java project.

Comment: better rewrite it in java

Comment: @furas nope, I have to use python function in java that's my requirement